# Getting the error "The name does not exist in the current context" when trying to reference a user control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I wanted to standardize popup in my application. So I created a user control for it and reference it as follow:

```
    <!--<Popup x:Name="LoginPopup" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="768" Width="1366" IsOpen="False">-->
        <uc:StandardDialog Name="StandardDialog" Height="768" Width="1366" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            .
            .
            .
        </uc:StandardDialog>
    <!--</Popup>-->
```

And in the code behind:

```
    private void LoginClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StandardDialog.IsOpen = true;
        //LoginPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void CloseLoginPopup(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StandardDialog.IsOpen = false;
        //LoginPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }
```

However this failed with the following error, which points to the lines above:

> Error 1   The name 'StandardDialog' does not exist in the current
>   context   C:\NSyncHg\MyApp.WinRT\Views\TestVisualAwarePage.xaml.cs    46  13  MyApp.WinRT

However if I were to uncomment the popup above and revert to the built in pop-up, everything compiles and run.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the [`x:Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758295.aspx) attribute, not just `Name`.

```
 <uc:StandardDialog x:Name="StandardDialog" ...
```

Windows Store applications don't automatically create a field for objects with their `Name` specified.  The `x:Name` attribute is required if you want a named field to be created and available to the code behind.

Comment: Reed, thanks for the save. Btw can you explain also why x:Name vs. Name? What's the difference and the reasoning behind it?

Comment: @Alwyn "Name' is just a property on the object.  `x:Name` is the directive that XAML uses to build a field (and also set the Name property, if it exists).  WPF will actually make both work interchangably, but Windows Store is pickier.